# How to run more than one JavaScript function with one click

Tags: javascript

How do I run five JavaScript functions in one click?

Sample code:

```
<img alt="move right" 
     src="Pictures/sides/right.gif" 
     id="MoveRight" 
     ***onclick="javascript:moveObjRight('ground','sky','mountain');"***
     style="z-index: 1; left: 801px; top: 37px; position: absolute; height: 33px; width: 34px;" 
/>
```

Comment: I guess function calls are made synchronously. You can make a call only after the prev call is completed. I am not sure though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<img alt="move right" src="Pictures/sides/right.gif" id="MoveRight"
    onclick="moveObjRight('ground','sky','mountain');myFunction2();myFunction3();myFunction4();myFunction5();"
    style="z-index: 1; left: 801px; top: 37px; position: absolute; height: 33px;
    width: 34px;" />
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    var ele = document.getElementById('MoveRight');
    ele.onclick = function() {
        moveObjRight('ground','sky','mountain');
        myFunction2();
        myFunction3();
        myFunction4();
        myFunction5();
    }
};
</script>
```

Note that the second option will override any previously assigned `window.onload` and `ele.onclick`function. If you are using a javascript library use the appropriate dom ready event (e.g. jQuery: `$(document).ready(function(){/*code*/});` or short: `$(function(){/*code*/})`)

Comment: @Thomas MyFunction2() will be called only after moveObjRight(..) right? Is there any way to call all the functions async?

Comment: is it possible to run functions in thread mode, i mean all functions run in one time not one by one?

Comment: not really, remember that all javascript engines (i'm aware of) run javascript synchronous - even when a event function like onclick is executed all other javascript on that page is halted.

Comment: not really, while you loose control to when it is run it will never execute 2 functions at the same time. `setTimeout`'s real purpose is to run a function at a later time (btw. note that it is not guaranteed that it will run exactly after the specified time/milliseconds).

Comment: i think its possible with setTimeout. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786646/stop-function-that-run-with-settimeout

Comment: You can make callbacks at the end of a function or run function after a certain time (`setTimeout`) or attach a function to a event (like onclick) however you can't make multiple functions run simultaneously (within a single page). To be clear if you want all five functions as in the example above to run onclick as fast as possible this is the right way.

Comment: Javascript is **single threaded**, you can't run functions asynchronously. You can run xmlHTTPRequests asynchronously, but when they return, their callback functions will be placed in a queue and run in their turn. setTimeout allows functions to be run after some interval, but does not provide any kind of asynchronous behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

You can add all your functions in the onclick property of the img tag

```
<img onclick="fnc1();fnc2();..." />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call a single method on your on click event and in that method you can call all your other methods.

Answer (score 0):

Call multiple functions in an other function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function CallMultipleFunctions() {
     Function1();
     Function2();
     Function3();
     Function4();
}
</script>

<img onclick= "CallMultipleFunctions()"/>
```

**EDIT:**

Check this [link](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/02/JavaScript-Function-Tips-and-Tricks.aspx)

Comment: is it possible to run functions in thread mode, i mean all functions run in one time not one by one?

Comment: For all programming considerations, Javascript is single-threaded`[1]`

However, because the web browser model is single-threaded, all four functions *will* run before the user gets control back.  You'll need to say why you need something different before we could advise you on other solutions.

`[1]`Yes, there are web-workers, but those can't interact with the UI so I'm ignoring them.