# stop function that run with setTimeout

Tags: javascript

I want stop my function that run with setTimeout and do not show image followed mouse. I want do that with button click, how do that?
my code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var trailimage = ["test.gif", 100, 99];
    var offsetfrommouse = [-25, -25];
    var displayduration = 0;
    function truebody() {
        return (!window.opera && document.compatMode && document.compatMode != "BackCompat") ? document.documentElement : document.body;
    }
    function hidetrail() {
        var x = document.getElementById("trailimageid").style;
        x.visibility = "hidden";
        document.onmousemove = "";
    }
    function followmouse(e) {
        var xcoord = offsetfrommouse[0];
        var ycoord = offsetfrommouse[1];
        if (typeof e != "undefined") {
            xcoord += e.pageX;
            ycoord += e.pageY;
        }
        else if (typeof window.event != "undefined") {
            xcoord += truebody().scrollLeft + event.clientX;
            ycoord += truebody().scrollTop + event.clientY;
        }
        var x = document.getElementById("trailimageid").style;
        x.left = xcoord + "px";
        x.top = ycoord + "px";            
    }

        alert("obj_selected = true");
        document.onmousemove = followmouse;
        if (displayduration > 0)
            setTimeout("hidetrail()", displayduration * 1000);

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">

    <img alt="" id="trailimageid" src="Pictures/sides/sides-not-clicked.gif" border="0" style="position: absolute; visibility: visible; left: 0px;
    top: 0px; width: 50px; height: 50px"/>

</form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In the posted code you do not execute the timeout since the displayduration is 0. Also I suggest you change `setTimeout("hidetrail()", displayduration * 1000);` to `someVar = setTimeout(hidetrail, displayduration * 1000);` where someVar is defined where your clearTimeout can get to it. Removing the quotes removes the hidden _eval_ which is considered evil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the return value of [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout), which is a "handle" for the timer, and when you want to cancel it, call [`clearTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearTimeout) with that value.

So in your code, you'd declare a `timerHandle` variable somewhere appropriate, then set it here:

```
if (displayduration > 0)
    timerHandle = setTimeout("hidetrail()", displayduration * 1000);
```

...and then create a button `click` handler:

```
function cancelTimeoutOnClick() {
    if (timerHandle) {
        clearTimeout(timerHandle);
        timerHandle = 0;
    }
}
```

---

**Off-topic**: It's almost never best practice to pass strings into `setTimeout`, that's an implicit `eval`. In your case, just pass the function reference:

```
if (displayduration > 0)
    timerHandle = setTimeout(hidetrail, displayduration * 1000);
                          // ^--- Difference here (no quotes, no parentheses)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
var foobarTimeout = setTimeout(foobar, 1000);

...

clearTimeout(foobarTimeout);
```

See:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearTimeout

Answer (score 0):

you use timeout like >

```
var myTimeout = setTimeout(yourfunction);
```

and then you can cancel it >

```
clearTimeout(myTimeout);
```