# How can I load an InfoWindow after a small delay in Gmap V3?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, infowindow

One of my applications shows multiple location markers on a Google map. How can I show an InfoWindow after a short delay?

Here is my script:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', onMarkerClick);

//create a function that will open an InfoWindow for a marker mouseover
var onMarkerClick = function() {
    var marker = this;
    var latLng = marker.getPosition();
    infowindow.setContent(
        '<h3>Marker position is:</h3>' + latLng.lat() + ', ' + latLng.lng());
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
};
```

Answer (score 5):

`setTimeout` should do what you want. The number is the millisecond delay.

```
setTimeout(function() { infowindow.open(map, marker) }, 500);
```

Comment: Remember that you also need to clear the set timouts when new mouseover events are triggered.
More info can be found in this answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786646/stop-function-that-run-with-settimeout