# Stop infoWindow from disappearing

Tags: android, google-maps, marker, infowindow

I'm using the method onInfoWindowClick to get an infoWindow when clicking on a marker on my map.
Is there a way to stop that infoWindow from disappearing after a few seconds?

Comment: As far as I know, InfoWindows will only close when you click the close icon. But if you have created a function that will open an InfoWindow by a marker mouseover, you need to add this code for the delay: `setTimeout(function() { infowindow.open(map, marker) }, 500);`. The number is the millisecond delay. You also need to clear the set timeouts when new mouseover events are triggered. More information can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786646/stop-function-that-run-with-settimeout).

Comment: it is impossible since you cannot close the infowindow when you did not click the X button. maybe you implement the infowindow wrong